# tinymce code inserting, can't get it to work

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I enabled codesample plugin https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/codesample/
and to test it I entered just head tag like this

[image: first]

and it displays like this in the editor

[image: second]

when I save this to database it gets saved like this:

```
<pre class="language-markup"><code>&lt;head&gt;</code></pre>
```

When I reload the page all i get is this in the editor

```
<pre>&nbsp;</pre>
```

Database still looks like

```
<pre class="language-markup"><code>&lt;head&gt;</code></pre>
```

but there is no head tag visible in the editor. Any ideas why?

Comment: How are you loading the content back in to the editor?  Perhaps you could make a simple JS Fiddle or CodePen that shows what you are doing?

Comment: i am using php to write out the content so I do this <textarea id="postBody" name="postBody" class="postBody">{{$post->body}}</textarea> Textarea gets loaded with this http://i.imgur.com/LMNpZ21.png But TinyMCE does not initialise this correctly and shows up empty. Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When placing raw HTML into a `<textarea>` you need to properly escape the HTML code that you are placing in the `<textarea>`.  As you are not doing that the browser (and by proxy TinyMCE) is "cleaning up" the invalid markup as best as it can.

You can either:

1. Properly escape the HTML
2. Use the `setContent()` API to load your HTML
   into TinyMCE (as opposed to injecting the HTML into the `<textarea>`)

I would personally suggest the **second** option above as it completely eliminates the vagaries of injecting HTML into a `<textarea>`.

If you want to try the first solution I listed above you might do something like this if you were using PHP

```
<?php
  $content = "This string contains the TM symbol: &trade;";
  print "<textarea>". htmlentities($content) ."</textarea>";
?>
```

Every language I have used has some equivalent to `htmlentities()`.

Comment: hi Michael i have another problem. I put this in the editor <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> it gets saved to database like this <pre>
<code class="language-php">&lt;meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"&gt;</code></pre> when I print it with php <?php echo htmlentities($post->body); ?> all i get is this <pre class="language-markup"><code>&lt;meta name="csrf-token" content=""&gt; </code></pre> <p>&nbsp;</p> If I try to print that in the textarea of tinymce it dosn't initialise correctly ends up empty. Why are curly braclets removed? how can I print curly

Comment: Instead of fighting with entities and HTML in a textarea can you just use setContent() and throw the data in a JavaScript variable when you render the page?  That should eliminate all of this...